# Rewrite Magento deducting stock

Tags: magento-1.8, product, stock

How would I rewrite Magento deducting from stock levels from when a product is purchased?

I am guessing I would need to rewrite app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php but not too sure

Comment: are you want to rewrite model/stock/item.php

Answer (score 2):

Magento reduces stock when an order is place and when trigger below events

1. `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before`
2. `checkout_submit_all_after`

During two events trigger magento is call function `subtractQuoteInventory` at `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer` class.

In where magento  S`Subtract quote items qtys from stock items related with quote items products`

and function **_getProductsQty** `convert quotes items` to `array with information about used product qty and product stock item` and

**Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->registerProductsSale($items);**

this code is deducted qty from products and  s`et a flag to done stock dedicated $quote->setInventoryProcessed(true);`

As if `any of two events is trigger then second events did not dedicate stock item`